# Firestore file system optimization

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing a basic user file system that uses Firestore for file metadata and Cloud Storage for Firebase for storing actual files. Firebase Storage isn't exclusively used because we want to add several attributes to folders that could become cumbersome considering GCS doesn't have "directories".

In this system, there are two types of items: directories and folders. To limit Firestore writes, children currently do not have a reference to their parent directories. Parent directories have an array containing each of their child IDs, and paths are built by traversing down each parent's children array. This is done to make moving files easier (basically, we switch the child ID from one directory's array to another directory's array). Otherwise, we would have to write a new parent into every child whenever a folder moves.

This is the data structure:

```
interface Directory {
  id: string;
  entryType: "directory";
  name: string;
  createdTimestamp?: Timestamp;
  modifiedTimestamp?: Timestamp;
  owners?: string[];
  viewers?: string[];
  editors?: string[];
  children: string[]; // contains references to File's ID
  color: string;
  icon: string;
  root: bool;

}

interface File{
 id: string;
  entryType: "file";
  name: string;
  createdTimestamp?: Timestamp;
  modifiedTimestamp?: Timestamp;
  owners?: string[];
  viewers?: string[];
  editors?: string[];
  storagePath: string; 
  storageBucket: string;
  contentType: string;
  metadata: Record<string, string>
}
```

However, based on my observations, large companies providing drive services tend to provide a parent reference with each of their children. These large companies are less constrained by the cost of multiple writes and I have yet to find a fatal flaw in this system (besides some inconvenience when constructing file paths), so I'm curious whether someone smarter than I am can explain why a parent reference should or should not be added? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> To limit Firestore writes, children currently do not have a reference to their parent directories.

If the problem is related to the number of writes you perform in Firestore, then why are you not using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)? The write operations are free of charge.

> Parent directories have an array containing each of their child IDs, and paths are built by traversing down each parent's children array.

Since the Realtime Database is an entire JSON object you can simply create references to the files in Storage, using key-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. RTDB was my initial choice for the same reason. My lead said he wanted us to use Firestore though, so I'm working with that constraint.

Comment: If you cannot switch to the Realtime Database, then you should try to do the same schema in documents using maps.

Comment: Right now our filesystem is planned as being nestable with users able to share individual files, which could be unwieldy with maps (if I'm picturing this correctly). Also, I should clarify: I'd prefer to limit writes, but we're fine with spending more if it means our model is robust and adaptable. The main situation we are trying to avoid is if a user moves a directory with hundreds of documents, which would incur one write per document moved. But if a well designed system would naturally incur this write load, then I believe we'd be okay with it.